# code analysis incomplete for filename with a dash

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I had this problem for a while, and finally understanding what caused it was a good relief. 
So basically, python files with a dash ('-') in their name are not fully analyzed by PyDev. I only get the errors but not the warnings... (ie: unused variables, unused imports etc...)

Is this a feature? a known bug? Is there any work around?
I know that the dash is not allowed for python folder but does this apply for python files? (in my case, those are python scripts, without the .py extension for convenience).

For instance, in my bin project subfolder:

- commit or release script files are analysed A-OK
- add-input, select-files: warning are not reported.

Thanks for any hint on that.

Answer (score 2):

Python does not allow dashes in identifiers. Module names need to be valid identifiers, so any module file or package directory name with a dash in it is not importable.

On the other hand, script files (python files executed directly by Python, not imported) have no such restrictions. I'd say what you encountered is a bug in PyDev and you should report it as such.

Comment: Thanks for feed back.
I just went to sourceforge to report, but found something similar:
[http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3184985&group_id=85796&atid=577329]  (ID: 3184985)

So the status is: _Thou shall not have a python script with a dash or warnings won't be reported_?? (only errors, why do it half the way?)

I'm not sure why the ticket has been closed by Fabio. So I'll wait for his input before reporting it again.

And I do not get any warning when opening my file in eclipse as the bug fix suggest.
(using Pydev 2.7)

Comment: Well, it seems that in order for PyDev to analyze a file, it needs to import that file as a python module. Since that isn't possible with files that have dashes in the name you are out of luck there. It *could* be that the [PEP 302 import hooks](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) let you work around that restriction, though.

Comment: So if it's not PyDev which is reporting errors in my files with a dash, I wonder who is it.

Comment: @user1812832: Error reporting needs to parse the file differently; pylint and pyflakes parse the file as text, and do not need to import it.

Comment: Make sense. So enabling pylint in pydev might be an acceptable workaround in this case.